# Is there a way to throttle the bandwidth Visual Studio uses when getting code out of Source Control?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

When I get latest on a branch, Visual Studio will merely download the files in the background. The issue is that whilst the transfer is running, anything else network related is VERY slow on the same client machine. For instance, browsing to a ticket in the TFS web view (on-premise) is nigh on impossible until Visual Studio has finished the download.

Can I throttle Visual Studio, to limit how much network bandwidth it's using?

Comment: That's not a problem with Visual Studio or TFS, it's a problem with your infrastructure.

Comment: Hi spikey_richie, any update on this issue.  Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Have you figured out it?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have any related setting/configuration on TFS web portal or Visual Studio.

To narrow down if it's related to your hardware or network, you could try below ways:

- Open `%localappdata%/Microsoft/Team Foundation/x.0/cache` and delete
  all files, then restart Visual Studio and retry.
- Removing the mapping of all of your workspaces then re-mapping them.
- This being a desktop PC, is there a custom firewall/anti-virus
  installed, it may be causing interesting slowdowns as well.

If you still get same situation, you may have to upgrade your hardware and expand bandwidth for your working environment.